# How do I use class variables from class and instance methods which are mixed in via a Module

Tags: ruby, class-variables

I want to be able to make an option passed to my class method (auditable) available to instance methods. I'm mixing in both the class and instance methods using a Module.

The obvious choice is to use a class variable, but I get an error when trying access it:

> uninitialized class variable @@auditable_only_once in Auditable

```
class Document
  include Auditable
  auditable :only_once => true
end

# The mixin
module Auditable
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def auditable(options = {})

      options[:only_once] ||= false

      class_eval do
        # SET THE OPTION HERE!!
        @@auditable_only_once = options[:only_once]
      end
      end
    end

    private

    def audit(action)
      # AND READ IT BACK LATER HERE
      return if @@auditable_only_once && self.audit_item
      AuditItem.create(:auditable => self, :tag => "#{self.class.to_s}_#{action}".downcase, :user => self.student)
    end    
  end
```

I've stripped out some of the code to make this a bit easier to read, the full code is here: https://gist.github.com/1004399 (EDIT: Gist now includes the solution)

Comment: In the version on github there is only one @ in front of auditable_only_once when assigning (line 16) but you've fixed that in the code here. Have you tested the code with that fix? Does it still not work?

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, I actaully tried single and double @'s, so must have copied a newer version of the code to the Gist. Now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `@@` class instance variables is irregular and the number of of occasions when they're strictly required is exceedingly rare. Most of the time they just seem to cause trouble or confusion. Generally you can use regular instance variables in the class context without issue.

What you might want to do is use a different template for this sort of thing. If you have `mattr_accessor`, which is provided by ActiveSupport, you may want to use that instead of that variable, or you can always write your own equivalent in your `ClassMethods` component.

One approach I've used is to break up your extension into two modules, a hook and an implementation. The hook only adds the methods to the base class that can be used to add the rest of the methods if required, but otherwise doesn't pollute the namespace:

```
module ClassExtender
  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:extend, self)
  end

  def engage(options = { })
    extend ClassExtenderMethods::ClassMethods
    include ClassExtenderMethods::InstanceMethods

    self.class_extender_options.merge!(options)
  end
end
```

This `engage` method can be called anything you like, as in your example it is `auditable`.

Next you create a container module for the class and instance methods that the extension adds when it is exercised:

```
module ClassExtenderMethods
  module ClassMethods
    def class_extender_options
      @class_extender_options ||= {
        :default_false => false
      }
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def instance_method_example
      :example
    end
  end
end
```

In this case there is a simple method `class_extender_options` that can be used to query or modify the options for a particular class. This avoids having to use the instance variable directly. An example instance method is also added.

You can define a simple example:

```
class Foo
  include ClassExtender

  engage(:true => true)
end
```

Then test that it is working properly:

```
Foo.class_extender_options
# => {:default_false=>false, :true=>true}

foo = Foo.new
foo.instance_method_example
# => :example
```

Comment: Note that I used cattr_accessor (not mattr_accessor) to create the class attribute (I'm in Rails so this works) and to access it from a instance method I used self.class.only_once